# Как вывести совпадающие по меткам посты, но исключая текущий?

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице записи в `single.php` вывожу совпадающие по меткам посты следующим образом:

```php
<?php  
  global $post;    
  $related_tax = 'post_tag';    
  $cats_tags_or_taxes = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $related_tax, array('fields' => 'ids')); 

  $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => $related_tax,
        'field' => 'id',
        'include_children' => false,
        'terms' => $cats_tags_or_taxes,
        'operator' => 'IN'
      )
    )
  );

  $misha_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($misha_query->have_posts()) :
?>

<div class="slider-box">
  <section class="related-tags-slider">
    <?php
      while ($misha_query->have_posts()) : $misha_query->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="related-tags-post">
      <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <div class="related-tags-descr">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </section>
</div>
<?php endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Выводит записи по меткам, но и текущую тоже. Подскажите, как исключить текущую запись?

Comment: Добавить в `$args` `'post__not_in' => [ YourID ]`?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но мне нужно не по ID, а текущую запись не выводить.

Comment: У текущей записи есть ИД. Значит надо взять те записи, ИД которых не равен текущей.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтоб это происходило на каждой записи динамически, а не на конкретной. Вариант по ID здесь не подходит. Или может есть вариант, как получить ID текущей записи и её не выводить?

Comment: `$post->ID` это и есть Ид текущей записи, разве нет?

Comment: Я в PHP новичок, не мог бы ты показать, как правильно должна выглядеть запись - $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array( 'post__not_in' => $post->ID  Вот так?

Comment: `'post__not_in'` добавляется не в `tax_query`, посмотрите [документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#postpages) и оно должно быть массивом. `$args = ['post__not_in' => [get_the_ID()], 'tax_query' => [[ // Ваши аргументы для так квери здесь... ]]`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Вот эта запись мне помогла - $args = array(
   'post__not_in'=>[get_the_ID()],.....